# Rotate through a zero based range for positive and negative numbers

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Say I have a zero-based range like

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

these are essentially the indexes of an array with size = 5. Is it possible to use a signed integer variable to continuously loop **up or down** in that range?

By up or down, I mean that the variable is permitted to perform **arbitrarily many increment or decrement operations**:

```
++index;
--index;
index += offset;
index -= offset;
```

So for example decrementing the index should map to following values:

```
index = 2;

while (/*...*/)
{
  --index;
  index_in_range(index, 5);
}
```

The function `index_in_range(index, 5)` would output:

```
1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, .... and so on
```

The positive case is just a modulo operation over the range size, but for the negative I can't figure out how the mapping goes.

EDIT :

The requested function `index_in_range(int idx, int range)` takes an arbitrary integer, i.e. could be called as `index_in_range(-245, 14)`. The example given does use a decrement operator but I never said I'm only offsetting by one each time.

Comment: Just using simple `if` conditions with changing the index accordingly, so it is in range, is rather simple and efficient. Why do you not want to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for the modulo operator? I don't get why it doesn't seem to work for you. In any case, please specify the programming language you want to use, not two of them!

Comment: Just checking... is `index_in_range` supposed to return an `int`? The formatting mislead me to believe you wanted it to return an array, but it's still unclear to me

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It's the sort of thing where the relationship between C and C++ guarantees that an answer to one is an answer to the other.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Check the accepted answer and comments therein . Modulo does not cut it here, I need to decrease the index as well, making its value possibly negative.

Comment: You could create a custom type for this in C++, @Sneftel, but not in C. In any case, we're all guessing here because the question is unclear.

Comment: A negative value is not part of your range. It's "loop up or down in that range" which you asked about. That's the reason I asked you to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C made a really poor decision for `%` to round towards zero, rather than be a straightforward floor, so the math's clunkier than it has to be. Basically, though, you want `(index % size + size) % size`. That code starts by chopping off the negative or positive multiples to bring the index into the range `(-size, size)`, adds `size` to map it into `(0,size*2)`, and a final `%` to map it into `[0,size)`.

If `size` is not known at compile time, it's likely more performant to replace everything after the first modulus with a conditional: `index %= size; if(index < 0) index += size;`.

Comment: Tried the first formula and it returns 0 when index is -1. Basically I'd like -1 to map to 4, so decreasing from 0 would send me at the other end of the array

Comment: @LorahAttkins `(-1 % 5 + 5) % 5 = (-1 + 5) % 5 = 4 % 5 = 4`. If you're seeing something different, you might be using unsigned types.

Comment: You're right , I had a similar formula (a bit more complicated) and ended up with the same sequence e.g. [2, 1, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3...] (i.e. 2 zeros at the first range length going downwards). But after changing the size of the range argument from `size_t` to `int` both ways worked

Comment: `index %= size` uses a division. Since we always know whether we are doing an increment or decrement, we can merely use `--index; if (index < 0) index = size-1;` and `++index; if (size <= index) index = 0;`.

Comment: I'm amazed at the percentage of people that got the question wrong. I feel like I over explained but nothing got through, so probably my wording is off - or people didn't bother  to read the text idk. @Sneftel any tips to improve my wording to convey what you understood?

Comment: Showing `[0,1,2,3,4]` may have worked against you by putting people in mind of an array. And describing the desired effect both as an inc/decrement loop and as a mapping function may have increased the cognitive load. I might have described what I wanted through a number of input->output examples. But I don’t think there were any serious problems with your description.

Comment: Remember, if you explain something n ways, people have to mentally make n*(n-1)/2 connections between them, and resolve (or wonder about) any perceived inconsistencies between them. So best to pick just a couple of well-defined and complementary framings.

Answer (score 1):

To increase

```
index = (index+1)%size;
```

To decrease

```
index = (index-1+size)%size
```

Comment: The function `index_in_range` can receive an arbitrary signed integer and a size to denote the range. So that function cannot control the offsetting of the index. Essentially I want to answer stuff like `index_in_range(-123, 14)` , the fact that `index=-123` does not mean I can control how the index got that value. But if I could control the value of index, your answer looks good +1